# Images not loading when path is correct PHP, Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image

I've got a script that loads some images and I have a `$dir` variable that provides an absolute path to those images (and then looks for either `.jpg` or `.png` files).

`$dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/assets/img/universities/';`

The path to the file is below:

`/www/html/uniswales.ac.uk/htdocs/wp/wp-content/themes/roots-master/assets/img/universities/University1.jpg`

The path to the images is correct but it won't load the images. I assume it's a permissions issue but not to sure.

This works on a site which I built from scratch but not when using it on a Wordpress site.

The permissions on the `img` files in the directory are `644` and the directories is `755`

**UPDATE**

When I echo `$dir`  `http://www.uniswales.ac.uk/assets/img/universities/`

Here's my whole script:

```
 $a = array();
                $unis = array(  "http://www.aber.ac.uk/en/", 
                                "http://www.bangor.ac.uk/",
                                "http://www.cadarn.ac.uk/",
                                "http://www3.cardiffmet.ac.uk/", 
                                "http://www.cardiff.ac.uk/", 
                                "http://www.glyndwr.ac.uk/",
                                "http://www.open.ac.uk/",
                                "http://www.swansea.ac.uk/",
                                "http://www.southwales.ac.uk/",
                                "http://www.uwtsd.ac.uk/",
                                "http://www.wales.ac.uk/");

                $count = 0;
                $dir =  get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/universities/';
                echo $dir;
                if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
                  while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                    if (preg_match("/\.png$/", $file)) $a[] = $file;
                    elseif (preg_match("/\.jpg$/", $file)) $a[] = $file;
                    elseif (preg_match("/\.jpeg$/", $file)) $a[] = $file;
                  }
                  closedir($handle);
                }

                sort($a);

                foreach ($a as $i) {
                    echo $i; 
                    echo "<div class='col-sm-4'>
                            <a href='". $unis[$count] . "'>
                            <div class='grid-box'>
                                <img class='uni-image' src='" . $dir . $i . "' />
                            ";
                    echo "<h5>" . pathinfo($i, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . "</h5>";
                    echo "</div></a></div>"; //END OF COLUMN 
                    $count++;
                }
```

This script works perfectly on sites that are NOT Wordpress. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sending this path to the browser? You cannot use absolute server paths on the client side.

Comment: Please check the source of the `img` tag and run over the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using:

```
$dir = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/universities/';
```

As was mentioned in the comments, you can't use absolute server paths for things that are being output client side.

Note: [get_stylesheed_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) will retrieve the stylesheet directory URI for the current theme/child theme. If you are using a child theme, and need the parent theme directory, use [get_template_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri).

Comment: That has provided me with an appropriate url `www.mysite.com/assets/img/universities/` but the images do not load still :/

Comment: ...and that should have given you `www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/roots-master/assets/img/universities/`

Comment: I have this as a URL now ` http://www.uniswales.ac.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/roots-master/assets/img/universities/ ` which works in a browser. Just not in the PHP file :(

Comment: What is the result of the above if you `echo $dir;`?

Comment: I'm updating my question with the full script.